# How would you build a simple bidding system with countdown?

Tags: architecture, websites

So I'd like to build a simple website where there's a given amount, let's say $1.

If someone pays that amount a 24 hour countdown starts. Within this window, people can outbid the previous amount and the countdown resets. That said, I have some doubts:

- Would it be possible to do it using ready to use solutions? (E.g. Stripe + bidding solution)
- Regarding the payment, how can I ensure that when a user bids he doesn't cancels it or doesn't want to pay the amount anymore?. Do payment gateways provide a similar feature?.

I'm really sorry if this question does not belong to this community. If so, I'd really appreciate any advice as for where should I ask.

Thank you very much!

Comment: It's not very clear what specific question you want us to respond to. If you are asking about non-repudiation of bids (preventing the user from cancelling or refusing to pay), there are great questions in that area. So maybe you should spell out what you have considered and refine this question. Asking if it's possible to implement using off the shelf solutions is off topic here. This is not a product selection forum.

Answer (score 1):

Responding the question about preventing repudiation of bids, some simple answers are...

1. Pre-Pay Model: Require the bidder to purchase credit when (or before) making a bid.

   - This is a lot like a pre-paid mobile phone account.
   - Then take the credit when the bidder wins the auction.
   - Leave the credit when the bidder loses the auction.
2. Credit Card Model: Get approval for the bid charge on the bidder's credit card for the amount they bid.

   - Get appropriate agreements in place that the bidder agrees to pay the bid amount if the auction is won.
   - When the bid is placed, request approval for the charge from the credit card company. This prevents the bidder from dramatically overbidding his/her credit limit.
   - When the auction is won, place the actual charge.
   - If the auction is lost, cancel the approval.